# Term's name that has an opposite meaning if translated literally

Tags: meaning, word-request, terminology

In my language, there's a term "*dikuliti*". The meaning is "to peel the skin off".

But that term is actually a passive verb of "*kulit*" (means skin). So the literal meaning of "*dikuliti*" is actually "skinned", "to put the skin on", opposite meaning.

Does English have words like this? If so, what is it called? Or is it just a weird system in my language.

Comment: The English verb [*skin*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skin#h2) has different senses. Confusingly enough, one means to peel skin off, the other to put it on. (In normal use, the former is more common.) So, your translation is actually still okay.

Comment: In addition to @JasonBassford's comment, skinned can also mean 'has had the skin removed' and also 'has had skin applied'. It depends on the subject to know which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is **contronym**. Contronyms, also known as [auto-antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) or contranyms, are words that have opposite meanings.

Some classic examples include *dust*, *sanction*, and *cleave*.

*To dust something* can mean to remove small particles off it or to sprinkle with small particles. For example, you can *dust a cake with powder sugar* or *dust the table.*

Similarly, *sanction* can mean "to give permission to" or "to impose a penalty on" something.

> The protest has been sanctioned by the government.
>
> The government will take action to sanction crime.

When you *cleave to a cliff*, *a person*, *a thing*, or *an activity*, you stick to it or be attached to it. But if you cleave wood, you cut it apart.

There's a long list of these verbs. [This page](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/75-contronyms-words-with-contradictory-meanings/) has some more examples:

> 1. Apology: A statement of contrition for an action, or a defense of one
> 2. Aught: All, or nothing
> 3. Bill: A payment, or an invoice for payment
> 4. Bolt: To secure, or to flee
> 5. Bound: Heading to a destination, or restrained from movement
> 6. Buckle: To connect, or to break or collapse
> 7. Cleave: To adhere, or to separate
> 8. Clip: To fasten, or detach
> 9. Consult: To offer advice, or to obtain it
> 10. Continue: To keep doing an action, or to suspend an action
> 11. Custom: A common practice, or a special treatment
> 12. Dike: A wall to prevent flooding, or a ditch
> 13. Discursive: Moving in an orderly fashion among topics, or proceeding aimlessly in a discussion
> 14. Dollop: A large amount (British English), or a small amount
> 15. Dust: To add fine particles, or to remove them
> 16. Enjoin: To impose, or to prohibit
> 17. Fast: Quick, or stuck or made stable
> 18. Fine: Excellent, or acceptable or good enough
> 19. Finished: Completed, or ended or destroyed
> 20. First degree: Most severe in the case of a murder charge, or least severe in reference to a burn
> 21. Fix: To repair, or to castrate
> 22. Flog: To promote persistently, or to criticize or beat
> 23. Garnish: To furnish, as with food preparation, or to take away, as with wages
> 24. Give out: To provide, or to stop because of a lack of supply
> 25. Go: To proceed or succeed, or to weaken or fail
> 26. Grade: A degree of slope, or a horizontal line or position
> 27. Handicap: An advantage provided to ensure equality, or a disadvantage that prevents equal achievement
> 28. Help: To assist, or to prevent or (in negative constructions) restrain
> 29. Hold up: To support, or to impede
> 30. Lease: To offer property for rent, or to hold such property
> 31. Left: Remained, or departed
> 32. Let: Allowed, or hindered
> 33. Liege: A feudal lord, or a vassal
> 34. Literally: Actually, or virtually
> 35. Mean: Average or stingy, or excellent
> 36. Model: An exemplar, or a copy
> 37. Off: Deactivated, or activated, as an alarm
> 38. Out: Visible, as with stars showing in the sky, or invisible, in reference to lights
> 39. Out of: Outside, or inside, as in working out of a specific office
> 40. Overlook: To supervise, or to neglect
> 41. Oversight: Monitoring, or failing to oversee
> 42. Peer: A person of the nobility, or an equal
> 43. Presently: Now, or soon
> 44. Put out: Extinguish, or generate
> 45. Puzzle: A problem, or to solve one
> 46. Quantum: Significantly large, or a minuscule part
> 47. Quiddity: Essence, or a trifling point of contention
> 48. Quite: Rather (as a qualifying modifier), or completely
> 49. Ravel: To entangle, or to disentangle
> 50. Refrain: To desist from doing something, or to repeat
> 51. Rent: To purchase use of something, or to sell use
> 52. Rock: An immobile mass of stone or figuratively similar phenomenon, or a shaking or unsettling movement or action
> 53. Sanction: To approve, or to boycott
> 54. Sanguine: Confidently cheerful, or bloodthirsty
> 55. Scan: To peruse, or to glance
> 56. Screen: To present, or to conceal
> 57. Seed: To sow seeds, or to shed or remove them
> 58. Shop: To patronize a business in order to purchase something, or to sell something
> 59. Skin: To cover, or to remove
> 60. Skinned: Covered with skin, or with the skin removed
> 61. Splice: To join, or to separate
> 62. Stakeholder: One who has a stake in an enterprise, or a bystander who holds the stake for those placing a bet
> 63. Strike: To hit, or to miss in an attempt to hit
> 64. Table: To propose (in British English), or to set aside
> 65. Temper: To soften, or to strengthen
> 66. Throw out: To dispose of, or to present for consideration
> 67. Transparent: Invisible, or obvious
> 68. Trim: To decorate, or to remove excess from
> 69. Trip: A journey, or a stumble
> 70. Unbending: Rigid, or relaxing
> 71. Variety: A particular type, or many types
> 72. Wear: To endure, or to deteriorate
> 73. Weather: To withstand, or to wear away
> 74. Wind up: To end, or to start up
> 75. With: Alongside, or against

Comment: Ah I see. So my question is actually pretty off but your answer is what I'm looking for. Thanks.